# SSRS lookup condition after match values color

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a lookup expression working with two dataset. The lookup is working, but am finding it difficult to fulfil certail condition. I want the condition to show green color if the totaldownload matches, but if not matches it should show red background. The code  at the moment in lookup is

```
=Lookup(Cstr(Fields!register_number.Value) & Format(CDate(Fields!flight_date.Value), "yyyy-MM-dd"), Cstr(Fields!REG.Value) & Format(CDate(Fields!FL_DATE.Value),"yyyy-MM-dd"), Fields!TOTALDOWNLOAD.Value, "DataSetCountAIMS")
```

I tried to use this  below in the properties of the table but still not working. Where should i put the code :

```
=SWITCH(Fields!totaldownload = Fields!Textbox10, "Green")   --- color properties  
=Switch(Fields!totaldownload <> Fields!Textbox10, "Red")    ----- background properties
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets Say the text box where you do the look up is called "`lookupvalue`" (instead of some random text name like textbox1

Now you can do the color by doing this:

```
=iif(Reportitems!lookupvalue.value = Fields!textbox10.value,"Green","Red")
```

Comment: is giving the error the value expression for the textrun lookupvalue contains an error [bc30205] End of statement expected

Comment: i used this =IIF(Reportitems!lookupvalue.value = Fields!totaldownload.value,"Green","Red")

Comment: ensure you have all the closing brackets and check you haven't missed anything.. sometimes a simple thing like a space or a lack of space in the expression can generate that error.. make sure your fields are all correct as well.

Comment: thanks Harry. Actually the error was coming from the expression of the textbox not expression of the color properties. I have seen the error. Now working